# Using .Hidden or .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to Ignore Hidden Rows -- Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

This code uses .Hidden and is intended to ignore hidden rows, but the output fails to do so:

```
For j = [ESDataRow1].Row To lastEIRPSummaryRow
    If [ESPriPred100].Rows(j).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If [ESPriPred100].Rows(j) >= [ESPRiSpec100].Rows(j) Then
            y2count = y2count + 1
        End If
    End If
Next j
```

So I tried using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), which produces "Application-defined or Object-defined error":

```
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, 1), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, 1))

For Each cel In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If [ESPriPred100].Rows(j) >= [ESPRiSpec100].Rows(j) Then
        y2count = y2count + 1
    End If
Next
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you qualify the ranges with sheet references? E.g., `Sheet1.Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow,1)` ?

Comment: Your `For Each cel` construct is correct but you then try to use `.Rows(j)` when you haven't assigned j a value, and that will not be restricted to the visible cells anyway. You need to use the cel variable. It would help if you explained what the ranges are.

Comment: @LimaNightHawk, Nope, that's not the problem in this case, but thanks.

Comment: @Rory, good point, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub jzz()
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 5
    If Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Debug.Print "row: " & i & " is hidden"
    Else
        Debug.Print "row: " & i & " is not hidden"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Works for me, and I haven't been able to break it.

Can you test with such a simplefied sub? If that works, add 'complexity' step by step and see where it breaks.
If it doesn't work, test in a clean (new) workbook.

Comment: The problem may be that my range is filtered, which may not be the same as hidden.

Comment: Works on filtered ranges as well with me. Have you tested this simple sub? Did it work?

Comment: Your sub works, but it is effectively the same as my first code example, which does not yield the expected result.

Comment: So it failed to identify the hidden rows?

Comment: My sub fails to correctly increment the variable y2count.

Comment: Oh, ok. That was unclear to me. I thought it failed to identify the hidden rows. What are you trying to determine with the `[ESPriPred100].Rows(j) >= [ESPRiSpec100].Rows(j)`? Are you comparing 2 cell values? Because right now you do something that should throw an error. Comparing ranges is (I think) not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I am in fact comparing two cell values. [ESPriPred100].Rows(j) is the jth cell of the named range called [ESPriPred00], which contains a value. Same for [ESPriSpec100].Rows(j). I can tell you this: When I remove the outer If-then statement which contains the EntireRow.Hidden property, the y2count increments correctly *if* no rows are hidden. But sometimes rows are hidden, which is why I added that outer If-then. When I add this condition and hide some rows, the y2count increments, but the answer is not mathematically correct, which puzzles me.

Comment: Now I understand. Are both named ranges (`ESPridPred100` and `ESPRiSpec100`) on the same sheet and if so, do they start at the same row? Because if not, the visual representation will be quite distorted when rows are hidden. Did you try to step trough the code, to see what happens?